# Simple To-Do app just doesn't print to-dos

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am building a simple To Do application Using node js, express, mongodb and ejs.

My get Route renders the form and the post route handles post request on the form, they both work perfect, any time I insert a (todo) it gets saved and can be found in my Mongo compass.

But it does not appear on the screen as Todo App should be. It only prints out usual bullets of (ul). I don't know what I am doing wrong, here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/Todo-App", 
{useUnifiedTopology:true,useNewUrlParser:true,useFindAndModify:false,useCreateIndex:true});
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(upload.array());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret:"secret"}));

var todoschema = mongoose.Schema({
item:String,
});

var Todo = mongoose.model("Todo",todoschema);

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
res.render('home.ejs',{Todo:Todo});
});

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
var newTodo = new Todo({
    item:req.body.item,
});
newTodo.save((err,result)=>{
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    else{
        res.redirect('/');
    }
})
})

app.listen(8080,()=>{
console.log("App is running...")
})
```

Here is my code in the ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My To-Do Application</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Enter Item">
        <input type="submit" value="Add To List">
    </form>
    <%for(var i = 0; i < Todo.length; i++){%>
        <li> <%=Todo[i]%></li>
    <%}%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is here

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home.ejs', { Todo : Todo });
});
```

you are doing the `res.render` without finding the documents from db

I think we need to add a find query before doing `res.render`

it should be something like that

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Todo.find({}, (err, todos) => { // passing an empty object as a first argument to the find method means we need to get all the documents from Todo collection
        if (err) {
            throw err;

        } else {

            res.render('home.ejs', { Todo: todos });
        }
    });
});
```

hope it helps

Comment: Oh Wow it worked perfectly but , can u please explain why {Todo:todos} and Why You should find before rendering    Please please?

Comment: rendering means you will send the response to the ejs file, so you have to find all the records before go back the ejs